# How are sophomoric and sophisticated related?

Tags: meaning, roots

How are sophomoric and sophisticated related? I suspect they come from the Greek Sophia for wisdom.

Comment: "Sophisticated" means almost exactly the opposite of what it originally meant.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, they are related. The root word in **Soph**isticate and **Soph**omore (and **Soph**ia) is

## Soph

(*Greek*: Sophos, Sophis)

**Soph** means ***Wisdom***.

> E.g. Philosophy from philo- "loving" (see philo-) + sophia "knowledge, wisdom," from **sophis** "wise, learned.

A wonderful explanation from this [site](http://www.english-for-students.com/soph.html):

> This ROOT-WORD is SOPH which means WISDOM. It comes from the Greek sophos. The list points up the fact that the **SOPH** laughs at true wisdom at the very moment when he himself tries to appear wise. The poor **Spoh**omore is hard put to it pretending to be wise when he has only just come out of the freshman class. His **Soph**istication sits uneasily on his immaturity.

Answer (score 0):

https://www.dictionary.com/browse/sophomore?s=t

**Sophomoric**

... probably (as the dictionary maintains) by influence of folk etymology derivation from Greek *sophos* "wise" and *moros* "foolish, dull."

As for **sophisticated**, I'm afraid it is closely related to *sophism* and *sophistry*, with a bunch of negative connotations and, in some contexts, synonymous with *demagogue*.

That said, "wisdom" is most certainly the root of both.